# Error Date is incompatible with Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Obtengo el siguiente error al crear un `Stored Procedure`

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure stpCrearCitas, Line 53 Operand
> type clash: date is incompatible with time

```
create procedure stpCrearCitas (@idCitas int, @idRecordatorio int, @Descripcion nvarchar (100), @Fecha date, @Hora time)
as begin
    insert into Citas values(@idCitas, @idRecordatorio, @Descripcion, @Fecha, @Hora)
end
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. A la pregunta le faltan detalles. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla y crear un escenario adecuado. ¿Cual es la definición de la tabla `Citas`?. ¿Qué parámetros le pasas al procedure cuando lo ejecutas para que te muestre ese error, porque en tiempo de compilación no lo va a producir? También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque el orden de las columnas de la tabla no coincide con el orden de los valores en el procedimiento almacenado. Para evitar este tipo de problemas, siempre se recomienda incluir el listado de columnas en el `INSERT`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stpCrearCitas (
    @idCitas int, 
    @idRecordatorio int, 
    @Descripcion nvarchar (100), 
    @Fecha date, 
    @Hora time
)
AS
INSERT INTO Citas
(
    idCitas,
    idRecordatorio,
    Descripcion,
    Fecha,
    Hora
)
VALUES(
    @idCitas, 
    @idRecordatorio, 
    @Descripcion, 
    @Fecha, 
    @Hora);
GO
```

También es buena idea dar un formato más amplio a tu código para facilitar su lectura.